# Arduino LED Matrix to receive data from serial port very slow

Tags: arduino, led

I have tried to create an system with 60 x8 LED matrix controlled by Arduino,
and need to receive data from serial port, but serial port data is received  very slowly. How may I get data faster?

just a 'Hello' took 1min to be received,
Time :

```
01:02:34.342 -> H
01:02:50.130 -> He
01:03:05.925 -> Hel
01:03:21.704 -> Hell
01:03:37.484 -> Hello
01:03:53.270 -> Hello
```

1. Setup

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  matrix.begin();
  matrix.setBrightness(5);
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color(255, 0, 0));
  matrix.setTextWrap(false);
}
```

2. Loop

```
void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char c = Serial.read();
      if(c != '\n') {
        s += c;
        //delay(1);
      }
      else
      {
        scrollText(s);
        scrollText(s);
        scrollText(s);
        s ="";
      }
      Serial.println(s);
  }
  scrollText("SmartView");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the baud rate of your communication protocol? Try **Serial.begin(19200);**, for instance, and don't forget to change the rate at the *Serial Monitor* as well. Sending and reading strings via serial communication is inherently slow, specially when using the built-in functions from the Arduino library, but, this should help

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the matrix LED library you are using and it certainly has nothing to do with the speed of the serial port. At 9600 baud it should take 1 ms to send a single character so you should be able to receive 1000 chars per second. If you explain how you are sending data to the other end of the serial port and what matrix lib you are using somebody might be able to offer some help

Comment: Change the `if (Serial.available())`to a `while`. `Serial.println(s)` in the loop takes much longer to execute than it takes to receive 1 byte.  Printing only complete lines will get you closer to full speed.